# How to test for floppy in drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using Windows XP Pro with Service Pack 3.

I have a .bat file that tests if various drives are available, and if they are then the bat file writes a little script that another program, an exe file, uses.

The problem is when the bat file issues the command to test if a disk is in the floppy drive, Windows generates an error and a message box.  Windows is doing its own testing and pops up a message box, which halts my bat file.  I don't want Windows to do the testing.

Here is a short bat file I wrote to demonstrate the problem:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

REM TEST FOR FLASH DRIVE
IF EXIST G:\NUL (
    ECHO Flash Drive found
)   


REM TEST FOR FLOPPY DISK IN DRIVE
IF EXIST A:\NUL (
    ECHO Floppy in Drive
)
```

How do I test for a floppy without Windows getting in the way?

Comment: Doesn't throw an error in Windows 7. I guess that is Windows XP specific.

Comment: The API to suppress this dialog is SetErrorMode; not sure if you can invoke that in the context of a batch file, though.  A quick search indicates you could do a dir command instead which does not show the dialog.

Comment: `pushd a:\ ` then check `%ERRORLEVEL%`

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the null operator, and have it just try the A: drive. This works for windows 7 so it might work for windows xp. or you can use a power shell command that list all active drives which is

```
get-psdrive.
```

Power shell has the ability to run commands like cmd with some more built in features.